# DevExpress LayoutControl mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: devexpress

I've created my first (BIG) LayoutControl and I'm puzzled by it's mouse wheel scroll handling. The control seems oblivious to scrolling while mouse is positioned above it. As far as I can tell, there is no way to focus it.

When I focus a TextEdit control on LayoutControl, mouse wheel scroll works on the entire control. This of course does not apply to LookupEdit controls which process mouse wheel scroll in their own way.

I've tried http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/eb922ed2-1036-41ca-bd15-49daed7b637c/ but all this does is scroll values in LookupEdit controls when mouse pointer is directly above them, nothing happens regarding scrolling in LayoutControl...

Is there a way to enable non-focused mouse wheel scroll on LayoutControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on DevExpress Q&A

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18512.aspx